# How to start MongoDB server on system start?

Tags: mongodb

I have to start my MongoDB server every time the system restarts. How do I configure it to start with my OS? I am on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Use this command to run after boot : sudo systemctl enable mongod

Answer (score 178):

According to the comments, on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS this seems to be the solution:

```
systemctl enable mongodb.service
```

Thanks to @Adam. I had the same "problem" on Debian jessie, and my solution there was:

```
systemctl enable mongod.service
```

Maybe they changed the name of the service.
I think in Ubuntu it's the same.

Comment: Worked for me on `Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 LTS`

Comment: This worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, MongoDB 3.4.4)

Comment: Pity there is no info in official documentation about starting the service.

Comment: may need to `(sudo) systemctl start mongod` to start the mongd service

Comment: Also works on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: worked for me on debian 9 too

Comment: Only works for me if I change `mongod.service` to `mongodb.service` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - strange?

Comment: @Adam not really, mongod is the deamon for the official version of mongodb from mongodb-org. mongodb is the daemon for the version that gets installed from the official ubuntu packages.

Comment: sudo systemctl enable mongod

Comment: There never was a [`mongod.service` in Ubuntu, even in 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=mongod.service&searchon=contents). [`monogodb.service`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=mongodb.service&searchon=contents) has been around or a while.

Comment: Use command : sudo systemctl enable mongod

Answer (score 41):

If you install MongoDB using the Advanced Packaging Tool (apt) then it'll configure your startup scripts to automatically run Mongo when the system boots.

The steps are as follows, first configure *apt* to be able to download the Mongo package:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line to *sources.list* then save:

```
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

Then download and install Mongo with the [apt-get](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) utility:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

If you want to make any changes to config, edit your *mongodb.conf* and restart:

```
sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: If you want to later change it to **not** automatically start MongoDB on startup, edit `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`.

Answer (score 12):

Controlling all the init.d service links should be done with the update-rc.d tool

i.e. to turn on the mongod daemon in the default runlevels (i.e. turn it on at boot):

```
update-rc.d mongodb defaults
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto for more information. This link tells you everything you want to know about how to set programs at boot.

Comment: The 10gen MongoDB distribution does not use System-V style init scripts, you need to edit `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`.

Comment: do i need to do this?

Answer (score 8):

I am using crontab for Ubuntu. It works fine. To be able to edit file

```
Sudo crontab –e
```

Add this line to the file

```
@reboot sudo service mongod start &
```

The "&" sigh at the end help it to work background.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> for exit, press "Y" once prompted. And keep the file name as "crontab".

Comment: Start up at boot : 
     sudo systemctl enable mongod 
To verify mongo status, auth and version : 
     mongo --eval 'db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 })'

Answer (score 8):

If you have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, you can enable mongo to start on boot typing this in your console: 
`sudo systemctl enable mongod`
 I have used this approach with MongoDB Community Edition 3.6 and it works. Reboot your machine and test if mongo is running typing: 
 `sudo service mongod status`

Answer (score 6):

If you have installed the [MongoDB Community Edition](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) (which is the recommended way since it receives more frequent updates than the package distributed in the Ubuntu package repository) you [configure the start / stop behaviour of `mongod`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#run-mongodb-community-edition) via the [upstart init script](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#init-scripts) `/etc/init/mongod.conf`, which defaults to start the daemon automatically on boot

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
```

If you *do not* want it to start automatically, replace those 2 lines with

```
stop on runlevel [023456]
```

Comment: Will this start the server before anyone logs into the system?

Comment: @GabrielFair Yes

Answer (score 4):

You can use systemctl command to enable your mongo service at run at system boot.

Create a service such that

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
```

Place content in the file

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Service
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
```

after that you will be able to use service commands like

```
sudo service mongod start|stop|restart
```

and then if you want to make it up at machine boot, you can create mongod file under `/etc/init.d/`

Answer (score 2):

`chkconfig --levels 235 mongod on`?

where mongodb is the name of your service

Comment: The 10gen MongoDB distribution does not use System-V style init scripts by default (though one is provided), edit `/etc/init/mongodb.conf` instead.

Comment: @kynan Edit it how?  What do I change / add to the mongod.conf file?

Comment: @Kieveli: see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/765191/22375)

Answer (score 2):

If you install MongoDB with `apt-get` as described [in the MongoDB Ubuntu installation guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), it will come with a basic startup script and config file. (use of a config file is highly recommended)

You can also take a look [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/ba9bd84cdd4c7377) for an old post that links to an `init.d` script.

In either case, the basic premise is that you're setting up a service and then configuring to start-stop with the computer. This is pretty common technique for servers, there are lots of tutorials around for doing exactly this.

Comment: no longer the case in 16.04

Answer (score 2):

For a default installation using apt, you can start it with following command

```
sudo service mongod start
```