# What is the correct way to ensure `mongod` starts on system startup in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

I installed MongoDB through the software centre in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
mongodb 1:2.6.10-0ubuntu1
```

I believe [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mongodb) currently contains MongoDB 2.6.10.

I am running an application on apache2 localhost setup and have to start `mongod` manually each time the system starts with:

```
mongod
```

I want it to start automatically.

I've come across two main methods to do this:

```
update-rc.d mongodb defaults
```

from:  https://askubuntu.com/a/89914/367134

which results in:

```
update-rc.d mongodb defaults
insserv: fopen(.depend.stop): Permission denied
```

But this didn't produce error:

```
sudo update-rc.d mongodb defaults
```

I've also seen a few references to edit the "MongoDB config file", but I'm not sure what this refers to as I can see config files in more than one location:

- `/etc/mongodb.conf`
- `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`
- `/etc/init.d/mongodb`

And, once in the correct file, I'm not sure what to change in there.

In `/etc/init/mongodb.conf` I can see:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
```

What is the correct way to ensure `mongod` starts on system startup in 16.04?

I've been reading [this](http://www.pathbreak.com/blog/ubuntu-startup-init-scripts-runlevels-upstart-jobs-explained), and looked in `/etc/rc2.d` and can see:

```
S01mongodb@                       --> /etc/init.d/mongodb
```

**Update:**

After running suggestion:

`sudo systemctl enable mongodb`

and then restarting, running `systemctl status mongodb` returns:

```
* mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-04-18 23:42:28 AEST; 7min ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
  Process: 655 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=100)
 Main PID: 655 (code=exited, status=100)

Apr 18 23:42:27 me-comp systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database
Apr 18 23:42:28 me-comp systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=100/n/a
Apr 18 23:42:28 me-comp systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 18 23:42:28 me-comp systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Permission Troubleshooting**

`/var/lib/mongodb` = `drwxr-xr-x mongodb mongodb`.
`/var/log/mongodb` = `drwxr-xr-x mongodb mongodb`.
`/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` = `-rw-r--r-- mongodb nogroup`.
`/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` = `-rw-r--r-- mongodb mongodb`.
`/data/db/mongod.lock` = `-rwxrwxr-x me me` and 0 bytes.
`/data` = `drwxr-xr-x root root`.
`/data/db` = `drwxr-xr-x me root`.

**Config File Contents**

`/etc/mongodb.conf`:

```
# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
#port = 27017 ...
```

Comment: 16.,04 uses systemd, not upstart. Create a systemd service: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files

Comment: @EdiD - `systemd status mongodb` returns `Excess arguments.` and   `sudo systemctl enable mongodb` returns `Synchronizing state of mongodb.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mongodb`.

Comment: and after executing... `systemctl status mongodb` returns something ?

Comment: See update in original post for results.

Comment: When you execute `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf` manually does it start ?

Comment: returns:  `2016-04-19T00:28:17.310+1000 SEVERE: Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"`

Comment: Permissions info added to original post.

Comment: I think by starting it manually you have now messed up the permissions for the log file (and probably others) - same fix as here required: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12232668/1148648

Comment: Also, 2.2 is ancient, see here for using more up to date versions on 16.04: http://askubuntu.com/a/757385/130555

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Installing**

This is the method I ended up using (from user Adam C's comment re: using more up to date version of mongodb).  It worked for me but I'm not an authority on the matter.

https://askubuntu.com/a/757385/367134

Then I had to make a service file, see:

https://askubuntu.com/a/694226/367134

And edit the path in that service file from:

```
/etc/mongodb.conf
```

to:

```
/etc/mongod.conf
```

And then make mongodb start on system startup with:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

see:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Now mongodb is starting on 16.04 system startup.

**Uninstalling Old MongoDB**

*Before* I did that however, I had to remove the existing installs and directories, which i did like this (steps mainly from https://askubuntu.com/a/497144/367134):

```
# go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d and remove any mongodb lists, then:

# sanity check - see what is installed
sudo dpkg -l | grep mongo

# remove all packages 
sudo apt-get remove mongodb* --purge
sudo apt-get autoremove

# remove old directories
sudo rm -r -f /var/lib/mongodb/
sudo rm -r -f /var/log/mongodb/
```

Comment: If anyone is getting `mongodb.service: Main process exited` stuff, make sure you don't have both  `mongodb` and `mongod` services trying to run. Use `systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled` to list enabled services. You may have accidentally enabled both (like I did), or the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

While you're developing you may also want the opposite sometimes: to have multiple local separable instances that you start individually, rather than one global install...

```
mongod --dbpath ./mongo_db_data/ --logpath ./mongo_logs/mongodb.log --port 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works just doing `sudo systemctl enable mongod`

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is because of the wrong permission of db path. just

```
chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```